# mouseclick sometimes fails to work

Tags: actionscript-3

I used an `eventlistener` for `MouseEvent.CLICK`. If I click once, it sometimes wont shoot, but when I click again it shoots. Is this a problem within flash or my mouse? It's strange. Here is the code for my fire event.

```
function fire(m: Event)
    {
        //reset the cooldown
        //spawn a bullet
        //set the position and the rotation of the bullet
            b.rotation = turret.rotation;
            b.x = turret.x;
            b.y = turret.y;
            //add the bullet to the parent object
            parent.addChild(b);
    }
```

Comment: Does this problem occur mainly when you've just started the game? If so, try adding the code `stage.focus=null;` at the start of your code for that frame.

Comment: no, it happens often but randomly. usually the second click works but when i click once, it doesnt shoot.

Comment: Where did you add your event listener? To stage or some object? If it's a DisplayObject check if nothing is overlapping it (like TextField or something). Also add trace in function and see if it's being dispatched.

Comment: If you didn't use a random-function, the issue doesn't happen randomly ;-) -- we would need more code. Where the listeners are added and to which object?

Comment: It's added in the main class.